# Correct usage of: "of vs for"

Tags: prepositions

Not a native English speaker. Tried searching for an answer to this question online but couldn't find an answer. So I am trying here. Please help me.

> We do high precision and quality labeling **of** free-text, image, audio, and video data.

OR

> We do high precision and quality labeling **for** free-text, image, audio, and video data.

Comment: "Of" seems more natural to me, but the way you say "high quality" implies some physical aspect to the label, and I'm struggling to see how you apply a label to those things listed (because they seem to be virtual things). You should expand your question to say what you're actually doing in this process you're trying to describe. These make more sense: *We create high precision, quality labels from free-text, image, audio, and video data*, or *We perform high precision, quality watermarking of image, audio and video data*

Comment: I don't like the use of *labeling* much (it's not very descriptive) but I suppose either *of* or *for* can work depending on what you do with the labels. *We do labeling of products* would mean you attach labels to products (but you might not create the labels). *We do labeling for products* would mean you create labels for producst (but you might not attach the labels to the products). In either of these "do" is a bit too simple of an action - it doesn't sound very sophisticated. It would be better to clarify the action too, like "We create labels for.." or "We perform labeling of.."

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical, but with different meanings (though in practice they are probably interchangeable).

Generally we can nominalise a verb and its object using *of*:

> I/you/we label data -> labeling of data

So *labeling **of** free-text, image, audio, and video data* corresponds to a sentence something like "We label free-text, image, audio, and video data".

With *for*, there is no idiom "to label for something", so the *for* phrase does not naturally attach to *labeling*.

I can see two places that the *for* phrase can attach, though in both cases, *labels* would be more natural, and it is awkward with *labeling*.

One is that it is a complement of *provide*: "to provide X for Y" means to give X to  Y, or to make X available for Y. So it would be natural to say *We provide labels for free-text, image, audio, and video data*.

The other is that the noun *label* (but not the verb) **can** take a *for* phrase: *These are labels for my paintings*. Again, using *labeling* there is odd, but possible.

In either of these cases I would read *labeling* not as a verbal noun "The act of labeling", but as a sort of collective: the collection of labels that may be required. Compare the various concrete meanings of *fixing(s)*.